# How to fill two related tables via a foreign key in a trigger function?

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables which I want to fill their corresponding FOREIGN KEYs simultaneously through a TRIGGER at the time of inserting data into `customers` table:

```
CREATE TABLE customers (
    customer_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    sld_id integer,
    customer_name varchar(35)
);

CREATE TABLE slds (
    sld_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    customer_id integer,
    sld_code varchar(8) UNIQUE
);


ALTER TABLE customers
ADD CONSTRAINT customers_sld_id_fk
FOREIGN KEY (sld_id)
REFERENCES slds(sld_id);

ALTER TABLE slds
ADD CONSTRAINT slds_customer_id_fk
FOREIGN KEY(customer_id)
REFERENCES customers(customer_id);
```

I have tried to use an AFTER INSERT trigger function, but NEW.customer_id returned NULL.

Then I used BEFORE INSERT which got me the value of NEW.customer_id. However, because of the constraint and the fact that the insertion didn't take place yet the FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINT is not fulfilled and I get an error.

I have read here that currval() and lastval() can be used but not recommended.

So I created a proxy table to store the generated values. Then, an AFTER INSERT trigger to fill in those fields back in the related tables.

I thought of using a CREATE TEMP TABLE, but found out that it only lasts for the duration of the calling function and not the connection session. Maybe I misunderstood the error message.

Is this a normal efficient practice? Namely, having a dirty table around just to use for such situations.

Or maybe there is another way to achieve this without using a proxy table?

EDITED:
SAMPLE DATA

```
customersTABLE:

customer_id          slds_id          customer_name
1                    1                johns
3                    2                jenn
4                    3                thomas
7                    4                jeff
8                    5                robin
9                    6                chris
10                   7                larry

slds TABLE:

slds_id              slds_code        customer_id
1                    SL747561         1
2                    SL710031         3
3                    SL719995         4
4                    SL765369         7
5                    SL738011         8
6                    SL722232         9
7                    SL751591         10
```

EDIT 2:

Forgot to mention that `slds_code` is generated within a trigger function:

```
sld_code varchar(8) := 'SL7'||to_char(floor(random() * 100000 + 1)::int, 'fm00000');
```

Comment: Please add some example data

Comment: Why there is a circular foreign key?

Comment: So you suggest one of them, possibly the one in `slds` table, should be dropped? Assuming I dropped it, would I still be able to fill in the `slds_id` field `BEFORE INSERT`?

Comment: Please add some sample data or insert query you are trying to reproduce your requirement

Comment: what does "random() * + 1" suppose to do ? a number multiply by +1 is always  itself. and floor(random() ) is always 0

Comment: That was a typo. Corrected. `random() * 100000 + 1`.